# How to add values to a floating point texture from within a fragment shader?

Tags: opengl, floating-point, glsl, textures, fragment-shader

Is it possible in GLSL to add to a floating point texture from within a fragment shader?

For example if i just want to know how often a fragment shader is called for one pixel, can i write a fragment shader that just adds 1 to the corresponding floating point texture pixel?

Because i only found how to set the output value, which is then just overwriting the old value or is somehow alphablended, which i think is a weighted multiplication and can not be used for adding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> which i think is a weighted multiplication and can not be used for adding.

No. [Blending](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Blending) can do more than a weighted multiplication. It's perfectly capable of doing additive blending; just set the source and destination factors to `GL_ONE`. That will reduce the equation to Src + Dst.

Comment: Wow, that is so simple it makes me think i violated the "search first, then ask" rule ;) Thank you very much! :)